# Pandas DataFrame manipulation based on Column value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Suppose I have a Pandas Dataframe in the format below based on a 'Dict of Dicts 'Group'list (also below)…

```
ITEMS={
    “Item_group1”:{‘Stuff’:’Some stuf’
            ‘More Stuff’:’Extra Stuff’
            Group:[[Iteration1, 18, 25,0], [Iteration1, 43, 67,1], [Iteration1, 87, 76,1],
                [Iteration2, 45, 29,0], [Iteration2, 44, 77,1], [Iteration2, 43, 74,0]],

            }
    “Item_group2”:{‘Stuff’:’Some stuf’
            ‘More Stuff’:’Extra Stuff’
            Group:[[Iteration1, 75, 564,0], [Iteration1, 21, 87,1], [Iteration1, 7, 5,1],
                [Iteration2, 54, 24,0], [Iteration2, 7, 45,1], [Iteration2, 45, 745,0]],
            }
```

DataFrame in the following format….

```
Iteration   Value1  Value2  Feature Active
Iteration1  18      25      0
Iteration1  3       67      1
Iteration1  87      76      1
Iteration2  45      29      0
Iteration2  44      7       1
Iteration2  43      74      0
```

How would I go about separating and calculating the averages for each iteration based on ‘Feature Active’ == 1, and ignore any ‘Feature Active’ ==0 entries?

I have the following code to calculate the stats per iteration for Value1 and Value2 after separating for ‘Iteration’ and ‘Feature Active’ as the keys, but it displays ‘Feature Active’ ==0 which I am not concerned with.

```
FeatureAvgs = Item_group1_DF.groupby(['Iteration’,’Feature Active'])
print np.round(FeatureAvgs[['Value1','Value2']].describe(), decimals=1)
```

Which produces the following output… (ignore the actual figures, this was taken from another dataframe)

```
Iteration   Feature Enabled
Iteration1  0               count   3672.0   3672.0
                            mean   -1352.5      0.0
                            std      220.5      0.0
                            min    -1920.0      0.0
                            25%    -1507.2      0.0
                            50%    -1267.0      0.0
                            75%    -1184.0      0.0
                            max     -785.0      0.0
            1               count    580.0    580.0
                            mean   -1368.6  -1394.5
                            std      151.5    157.7
                            min    -1788.0  -1805.0
                            25%    -1454.2  -1490.2
                            50%    -1335.5  -1361.0
                            75%    -1270.0  -1291.0
                            max    -1045.0  -1033.0
Iteration2  0               count  20612.0  20612.0
                            mean   -1073.5      0.0
                            std      142.3      0.0
                            min    -1730.0      0.0
                            25%    -1088.0      0.0
                            50%    -1036.0      0.0
                            75%    -1005.0      0.0
                            max     -805.0      0.0
            1               count  14718.0  14718.0
                            mean   -1113.6  -1161.1
                            std      129.3    134.9
                            min    -1773.0  -1818.0
                            25%    -1151.0  -1214.0
                            50%    -1095.0  -1122.0
                            75%    -1043.0  -1075.0
                            max     -832.0   -897.0
```

But I am just after the mean averages for when the feature is active (==1).  Sorry for the long question, but I am new to Pandas, and still getting through the documentation

Comment: can't you just filter the df first and then group? `FeatureAvgs = Item_group1_DF[item_group1_DF['Feature Enabled'] == 1].groupby(['Iteration’,’Feature Active'])[['Value1','Value2']].mean()`

Comment: Thanks EdChum, I didn't know you could edit the DataFrame before running a query on it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than filtering on the groupby object you can just filter the initial df first:

```
FeatureAvgs = Item_group1_DF[item_group1_DF['Feature Enabled'] == 1].groupby(['Iteration’,’Feature Active'])[['Value1','Value2']].mean()
```

Also there is no need to use `describe` if you just want the `mean` just use `mean`, as an aside you can access the `mean` column from the result of `describe` by using:

```
print np.round(FeatureAvgs[['Value1','Value2']].describe()['mean'], decimals=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood well, you can do:

```
> df.groupby(["Feature Active", "Iteration"]).mean().loc[1]

            Value1  Value2
Iteration                 
Iteration1      45    71.5
Iteration2      44     7.0
```

You `groupby` first on the feature, and second on the Iteration variable. On each group you apply the `mean()` function, and you get the group whose index is `1`, which correspond to the `Feature Active == 1` group.

With:

```
> df

    Iteration  Value1  Value2  Feature Active
0  Iteration1      18      25               0
1  Iteration1       3      67               1
2  Iteration1      87      76               1
3  Iteration2      45      29               0
4  Iteration2      44       7               1
5  Iteration2      43      74               0


> df.groupby(["Feature Active", "Iteration"]).mean()

                           Value1  Value2
Feature Active Iteration                 
0              Iteration1      18    25.0
               Iteration2      44    51.5
1              Iteration1      45    71.5
               Iteration2      44     7.0
```

Tell me if it's not what you wanted.

HTH